# Where can I see the source code of system API like write/read of linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu, tcp

I have downloaded the sytem source code from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/linux/3.2.0-44.69), but i can't find source code of read/write functions from the package. Could anybody tell me where I can get the code for these socket operation functions?

**[why I want to check the source code]**
I am developing a multithreaded linux application and need to know, if calling socket operation functions like write/read/sendmsg to access a same TCP socket from different threads concurrently is safe or not.

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981372/are-parallel-calls-to-send-recv-on-the-same-socket-valid

Comment: @deufeufeu I also read this post before making my own thread, but I am not satisfied with the anwser it provided, so I decided to check the source code myself:_)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can search a function and other things in the kernel source code on [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/).

But before you search, you should know that write/read/sendmsg are system call,and their definitions aren't like usually functions.
When you use read(), sys_read() works in fact,and itselves defintion is also confused:[here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.4/fs/read_write.c#L488)

here is [write()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.4/fs/read_write.c#L502) and [sendmsg()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.4/net/socket.c#L2096) .

If you want to know more about system call such as their definiton, you can read chapter.5 of Linux Kernel Development.

Comment: LXR is very useful!~ 3QU~

Answer (score 4):

1) Find out what library provides function you want to see source of

e.g. "man read"

```
NAME
   read - read from a file descriptor

SYNOPSIS
   #include <unistd.h>

   ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

2) locate header file, e.g. "/usr/include/unistd.h"

3) find out what package provides this file, with Debian/Ubuntu e.g.

```
pwadas@kehillah:~$ dpkg -S /usr/include/unistd.h 
libc6-dev: /usr/include/unistd.h
```

4) Download source package and browse code

there's probably many "read" functions available from various libraries. You might want to try

```
man 7 socket
man 7 tcp
```

or other relevant sources.