# TCP/IP Multithreading Application

Tags: multithreading, sockets, server, tcp, client

I have an Server/Client application and just wanted to address some concerns I have.

It uses TCP/IP sockets to communicate with each other.

My concerns is the following...

I have a section of code that handles a series of commands from the client (this multi-threads for EVERY user that is connected) this can have up to 20-40-60 threads.

I have dedicated thread to handle live chats for users online.

I have another dedicated thread that handles push notifications to the client.

My question is...  am I really doing it properly?

I am concerned that if a push notificaiton/chat/client command is processed at the same time, the client will receive the data incorrectly.

In a nutshell (of course hypothetically speaking):

Client Sends Command:  "Get-Me-Data"

Push Notification sends to same client:  "You_Got_Mail"

Chat Notification sends to same client: "MESSAGE"

I am concerned that client will receieve the data in this manner  Get-Me-MESSAGE-Mail-Data-Got

I heard of using SyncLock to prevent this,  should I syncLock the client NetworkStream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language and library do you use? If you use direct network stack calls without libraries managing streams then you will not encounter any race conditions - [network stack send function is atomic so you should be safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1981439/12396017)

Comment: vb.net TCPClient