# Is it thread safe to call socket send to different sockets from different threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

Hi I am new to C++/C and I have a question: Is it thread safe to call socket send to different sockets from different threads? I can find answer on stackoverflow that message may be jumbled upon receive when calling send() to SAME socket from different threads. What about calling send() to DIFFERENT sockets from different threads? Is it thread safe? Thank you.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

send(1, buf1, buf1.size(), 0); //call from thread1

send(2, buf2, buf2.size(), 0); //call from thread2
```

Comment: C or C++ ? Please correct the tags

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1981462/4885321) answer your question?

Comment: Yes it is thread safe.

Comment: Presumably this is Linux? Or at least POSIX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly safe for separate threads to call `send()` to *different* sockets at the same time.

Like you said, the only time you need to worry is when separate threads are trying to `send()` to the *same* socket at the same time, that needs to be coordinated accordingly.